# Replace zero sequences with the last non zero value - scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a column that intercalate and index and a sequence of zeros, that repeats a lot of times. I want to replace this zero sequence with the last non zero value.

I don't want to use a window function because the dataset it's too large and the partition will be very granular.

Example:
col
1
2
3
4
0
0
1
2
3
0

desired:
1
2
3
4
4
4
1
2
3
3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's not clear your problem. Could you give more details and also provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I also suggest to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you really need to use Apache Spark here? I mean, Spark is for really big data, not for few hundreds megabytes

Answer (score 1):

Try with window **`last`** function and using `monotonically_increasing_id` column.

**`Example:`**

```
%scala
import spark.implicits._

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val df = Seq((1),(2),(3),(4),(0),(0),(1),(2),(3),(0)).toDF("col").withColumn("mid",monotonically_increasing_id())
val windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy("mid").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn("col", when(col("col")===0,lit(null)).otherwise(col("col"))).
withColumn("desired",last(col("col"),true).over(windowSpec)).
drop("mid").
show()
//+----+-------+
//| col|desired|
//+----+-------+
//|   1|      1|
//|   2|      2|
//|   3|      3|
//|   4|      4|
//|null|      4|
//|null|      4|
//|   1|      1|
//|   2|      2|
//|   3|      3|
//|null|      3|
//+----+-------+
```